# writing bold both in text and formula properly

Tags: bold, boldmath

[image]

my question is actually about writing bold properly. When I try \mathbf in the formula, it works but I need to write J in the formula italic but somehow I could not manage it. And when I try to write bold in the paragraph by using \textbf, it works for  \textbf F(x) but does not work for \textbf F(x_n). I don't understand what is the problem. I attached the image of textbook I am trying to write in LaTex and put the LaTex writings below. Thanks for your helps.

```
\paragraph{Question 4.5}
Modify \verb|newton| from the previous exercise so that it works on a system of equations \textbf{F(x)}. The function \verb|fprime| now returns the Jacobian matrix \verb|J|, and the Newton update is written mathematically as 
\[\mathbf{
x_{n+1} = x_n - J^{-1}F(x_n)},
\]
    although in numerical practice one does not compute the inverse of the Jacobian but solves a linear system of equations in which \textbf{F(x_n)} is the right-hand side.
```

Comment: `\[\boldsymbol{
x_{n+1} = x_n - J^{-1}F(x_n)},
\]`? or `\boldmath\[
x_{n+1} = x_n - J^{-1}F(x_n),
\]\unboldmath`? And of course `$\boldsymbol{F(x_n)}$`.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!@Schrödinger'scat

Comment: Why not simply the pair `\boldmath \[ ... \] \unboldmath`?